# How do I enable automatic updates?

Tags: updates, unattended-upgrades

Update Manager is constantly offering me updates (e.g. security fixes, updates from PPAs).

How can I tell my Ubuntu installation to automatically download and install updates whenever they become available?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates

Comment: See also: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management#heading--automatic-updates

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this easily for security updates.

From System Settings open Update Manager. Click the 'Settings...' button, then on the 'Updates' tab, select the radio button 'Install security updates without confirmation.'

**To automatically install all updates, see the answer below.**

Comment: -1 Disappointing this has selected since this is not answering the question correctly and is showing a thing everybody who know Ubuntu a little bit and pays attention in dialogs knows this already. The most upvoted answer is the right one.

Answer (score 183):

Although it is not wrong or dangerous (see comments to this answer), using `apt-get upgrade -y` is not the best way to achieve this.

**unattended-upgrades** is **one of the best practices** of having automatic updates, especially for headless machines or servers!

You can set up unattended-upgrades pretty easily by typing this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

From the description:

```
 This package can download and install security upgrades automatically
 and unattended, taking care to only install packages from the
 configured APT source, and checking for dpkg prompts about
 configuration file changes.
```

Comment: Although I agree that those crontabs entries are not the way to go: apt-get upgrade -y is not *that* bad. From the man page for -y: "If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will abort."

Comment: But an important package for your server, web application, etc might not be an "essential" package and could potentially get removed.

Comment: `unattended-upgrades` is preferable but `apt-get -y upgrade` is not wrong or dangerous at all. `sudo apt-get upgrade` will **never** (with or with out `y`, with or without explicit user approval) install  any new package or uninstall any installed package. (From [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html): "under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages not already installed retrieved and installed.") Remember, the `-y` flag can be used with other, potentially more dangerous commands than `upgrade`, such as `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: This is lacking the info that you have to set `APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";` to 1 and should also set `APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";` to something in days in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` or not? Also you would not be do this instead of the GUI way if you would only security updates so you also have to uncomment `//    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` to really have automatic upgrades for all code packages. This can then be extended to update even more.

Comment: How often will the update run now, after I set this up?

Comment: daily, according to /etc/cron.daily/apt

Comment: What happens with updates that require a server reboot?

Comment: A file will be created by the system (/var/run/reboot-required) to let you know that a reboot is required. But no actions are taken by unattended-upgrades to restart the system though, it's up to you to restart it.

Comment: official docs talk about enabling notifications as well (via email), which i think is good for those who wish to know. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html

Comment: How can I do this without needing to interact with the prompt?

Comment: Does this also update my LTS version from 18 to 20?

Comment: The official docs appear to have moved here: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management#heading--automatic-updates

Answer (score 41):

In the Update Manager click the `Settings` button. This dialog will show up:

[image: screenshot of Download and install automatically security updates]

Select the "Download and install automatically". This will automatically install security updates. If you want to set this up for them remotely via, you can do this:

`sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades`

If the package is installed already you can do:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades`

to change it's behavior. Follow the prompts to enable the feature once you run the command. There's currently no graphical method to just set the entire system to update unattended for everything (you want to play it safe when it comes to automatic upgrades), but setting security updates automatically is a good idea.

Check out the pages for more information if you want to automate getting -updates and -backports:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates#Using_the_.22unattended-upgrades.22_package
- [How to enable silent automatic updates for any repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87849/how-to-enable-silent-automatic-updates-for-any-repository)
- [How do I enable automatic updates of all packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35053/how-do-i-enable-automatic-updates-of-all-packages)

Comment: You can start update manager from the command line with `update-manager`

Answer (score 24):

Go to terminal, and enter:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

Say "yes" to the prompt. You'll still be notified about "normal" updates, such as those that contain bugfixes, but security updates will be installed automatically.

Comment: Can I do it without a prompt? (So turn on unattended upgardes unattended :) )

Comment: This doesn't upgrade my LTS automatically, does it?

Comment: @Harsha No. you need to run dist-upgrade for that as new releases require a new kernel, and upgrade will never install a new kernel.

Answer (score 10):

I use `apticron` to get informed by mail if an update needs to be done.

In your case, I would use `cron-apt` or `unattended-upgrades` to do the job of automagically updating your machines.