# How to automate updates?

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable automatic updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9/how-do-i-enable-automatic-updates)

My Aunt and Uncle asked me to setup a Ubuntu machine for them, but here's the problem; they live 200 miles away, and are VERY computer illiterate.

So, my question is; how do I set the update system to be fully automatic? (IE: download and install the updates by itself) I know it's bad practice, but the altnertive is a diffrent distro or a lot of phone calls and fuel usage :/