# How can I set up Ubuntu to install updates without asking?

Tags: apt, updates, automation, cron-jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable automatic updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9/how-do-i-enable-automatic-updates)

I would like to have Ubuntu silently install updates every day or so. It it possible to set it to do so? Are there any potential dangers to doing things this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
```

`unattended-upgrades` can be quickly configured to let you upgrade more than just security updates although you should recognise that sometimes (mainly with Firefox in my experience) upgrades can break running applications. That's something you'll have to weigh up yourself.

To configure edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` but you can [read more about the configuration options on the help site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates)

Comment: Link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the Ubuntu Software Center, go to the menu "Edit" -> "Software Sources…", then in the third tab "Updates", there is the option to select "Install security updates without confirmation".  This will not install all updates automatically, but it will do so for security updates.

There are also other ways (see Oli's answer) in case you want all updates to be installed...

Potential dangers are the same as with all updates: every change can introduce new bugs...
(An that's even more so with updates that introduce more features, so it's probably reasonably safe for security fixes, but somewhat less so if you also have repositores like ubuntu-proposed or ubuntu-backports or some PPAs.)

Answer (score 0):

You need use **software sources** (Ubuntu 10.10 from *Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources*).

Select tab Updates, then the "Install security updates without confirmation". It only installs security updates.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) .

It should be as safe and running an interactive upgrade, except for the fact that if you get an issue from an upgrade you may not be aware in advance.