# How do I enable automatic updates of all packages?

Tags: updates, automation

I'd like to use unattended-upgrades to install all updates to Natty beta packages daily. Whatever I try, unattended-upgrades seems to ignore updates to packages in "main". Here's my current Allowed-Origins section of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`.

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id} stable";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-main";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-security";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-updates";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-universe";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-multiverse";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-restricted";
};
```

**Update:** Here's the working Allowed-Origins I came up with using the advice from the accepted answer:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id} stable";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-main";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-security";
    "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-updates";
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no -main, -universe, -multiverse, or -restricted repository.  Main, universe, etc are pockets within each repository.  Packages from all pockets in an enabled repository are installed.  There are only 4 repositories and they are all listed in that config file by default:

```
distro
distro-updates
distro-security
distro-proposed-updates
```

By default both updates and proposed-updates are commented out.  Simply uncomment the -updates line if you want all updates instead of only security related ones.

Comment: Thanks! I already had "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}-updates" in there but I was missing plain old "${distro_id} ${distro_codename}". I added that and now I'm getting all the updates.