# Ia32-libs issue

Tags: updates

I had my firestorm running OK but since I installed new cuda 5.5 it stop working, when I try to update it says it’s up to date ,gives me the following message.

My Ubuntu is 12.04, running on i7 processor, and Nvidia GeForce 640

ANY IDEA
THANKS

```
shams@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
[sudo] password for shams:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ia32-libs is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libcublas4 libnpp4 libvdpau-dev gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libcudart4 g++-4.4
libcurand4 nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-doc nvidia-cuda-gdb
libqtassistantclient4 opencl-headers libubuntuoneui-3.0-1
thunderbird-globalmenu libcusparse4 nvidia-compute-profiler libthrust-dev
libcufft4 libstdc++6-4.4-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1704 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I think here is your problem **"1704 not upgraded"**. Do sudo apt-get upgrade` and hope for the best.

Comment: cool, how often i should do this on my machine , Thanks

Comment: Err... dialy? [How often should I update my system?](http://askubuntu.com/q/150078)

Comment: Oh God, I cant take this anymore, i spent 8 days, not one hour a day but 14-15 hours a day just to solve my Ubuntu Issues optimize it and get it running and now when it was up and running i made the foolish step to ask for a help about lib32, If i knew i am going to end up  with a blue screen or there was a slightest chance to get into this ,  i would never had done this, 
as you suggested i upgraded and now my screen is completely blue, nothing but mouse cursor.  

Please somebody help.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What you did before the screen were all blue?

Comment: as suggested i upgraded and now my screen is completely blue, nothing but mouse cursor. I thought its some system file which will be upgraded, but now i see 13.04 when it starts, then nothing there on screen. when i press Ctrl+Alt+Del i get confirmation window it i want to log out, when i select yes, first time it goes to the log in screen, try logging in but its same. pics icon like Ubuntu ant the top right corner are marked "x" that gives me a feeling of some graphic problem. i dont know.  

Please somebody help.

Comment: Did you restarted? If the answer is yes, please follow the following: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381)

Comment: once update finished i just reboot my system using the top right button., it gives me Ubuntu Logo, and the screen with 4-5 points moving left to right. and then i see my mouse cursor, next there suppose to be a login screen. but there is only blue screen. when i press Ctrl+Alt+Del the i see a MS Window Xp type little window asking me if i really want to log off, when i slect yes then comes the login screnn. thats all. when i login again i get blue screen with two little icons at the top right corner with "x" on it.

Comment: Ok, apparently you have some driver issues and your system autologins. Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 type your user/password and type the following: `sudo apt-get autoremove` also type the command in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/174545/169736), then [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/68312/169736) and the commands included in the summary of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/206289/169736). Now type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and reinstall.

Comment: following the link provided by you, i went through the second command, when i try to pull the graphic display to see the CompizConfig Settings, i get error. "package nvidia-304-updates 304.88-0ubuntu2 failed to install/upgrade: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1"

Comment: Can you follow only the last link? Every of the links is to resolve the blue screen problem I don't know where you got that error.

Comment: I did follow the last link, after it finish when i restart it runs many Staring procedure after that it stuck on "starting crash report submission daemon" then nothing happens. next time started, after the logo screen just screen went black with blinking cursor on top lift corner.

Comment: when i reboot the system after waiting for long time at black screen it shows  something like winbind daemon stopping or something before it goes off.

Comment: Ok, now you are at [this stage.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) Check the answers that fit to your situation.