# Nice way to manage multiple Ubuntu servers

Tags: 12.04, server, stable-release-updates

I need to manage 10+ ubuntu 12.04 servers running both inside a company network and on the internet. I am looking for an easy way to keep all boxes updated with the latest packages (**without autoupdates**),but don't want to use landscape. Some "easy to use" interface would be nice. Is there a tool i missed, while googling?

Comment: its simple: use ssh!

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/204/178596) for security updates...

Comment: Autoupdates are not an option on production servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use **puppet**
Here You are an Example: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hiu_ui2nZa0