# lubuntu 20.04 Update Notifier window poping up on nonadministrative user

Tags: lubuntu

I have installed many computers with lubuntu 20.04 for users on our network and I added for them nonadministrative user called "user".
Very often window with new updates "Update Notifier" will pop up. Is there any way how to set updates to install them automatically or set the window to pop up just once a day?
They cant install it with their account - they dont have sudo rights.

Edit: **Answer:**

Possibly turn off updates in GUI (testing it now) and:

`sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades` `sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades`

in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`
if not, set `APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages` `0` to `1`, set `APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval` `0` to something in days

in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` uncomment `${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/5332/1001338).

Comment: Found in the Lubuntu manual here - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.3/software_sources.html   (I agree with @ParsaMousavi )

Comment: @guiverc There isnt any option to install all updates automatically mentioned in manual, only security which I have already checked. It doesnt help with window poping up every 5minutes :/

Comment: I would jump to terminal & ensure system is fully upgraded (ie. `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` noting the output to ensure all upgrades have been applied).  If a package is held (`apt-mark hold` or equiv.) then being constantly nagged could be expected..or it could be something from a 3rd party source, but I'd expect those commands to provide a clue..  You could ask on https://discourse.lubuntu.me/ as it maybe seen by HMollerCl who I think wrote the *Update Notifier* too (if I've remembered incorrectly the *devs* will be there anyway)

Comment: @guiverc Everything is ok - there are updates to install, just not security.