# How can I get ubuntu or apt to automatically install all updates without the Software Updater popup?

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, update-manager

If updates are available when I boot up, software updater will prompt me saying "Updated software is available for this computer. Do you want to install it now?". Its a mild inconvenience sure, but an inconvenience nonetheless. I would like to just not think about updates, and have them automatically install themselves as soon as they're available.

In the "Software & Updates" settings, I have security updates set to automatically install but I don't know how to get any other updates to automatically install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable automatic updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9/how-do-i-enable-automatic-updates)

Answer (score 0):

Some upgrades are automatic, whether you like it or not:

- Snaps
- Packages in the Ubuntu repositories' -security pocket

Some upgrades should NOT be automatically upgraded. An untested upgrade might break your system.

- Packages in the Ubuntu repositories' -proposed pocket, -backports pocket, and testing PPAs
- Non-Ubuntu repositories and PPAs that provide third-party packages that may conflict with the installed system.

  This means that common applications like Chrome or Plex are poor candidates for automatic upgrades, since their compatibility is untested. Well, YOU are doing the testing.

This limits the number of safe upgrade sources to basically the Ubuntu repositories' -updates pocket. But that's still a lot. It includes most of the packages that you see whenever Ubuntu nags you to upgrade.

---

**How to add -updates to Unattended Upgrades**:

Edit line 14 of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

```
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
```

Uncomment the line by removing the `//` at the beginning of the line. Leave the rest.

Save your change. That's it. You're done.

No need restart, no need to reload anything.