# Proper setup for automatic updates for my kid's computer

Tags: apt, updates, administrator

My young kid is using a Linux computer with Ubuntu installed by default.

She has a restricted normal user account and no administrator rights. I don't want to give her admin rights just yet.

As a result, she now needs my help to install package updates.

That's fairly annoying.

What is a proper way to automate package updates with minimal or no involvement by the non-admin user on the machine?

Comment: Hey Hanno! Which version of Ubuntu is installed in the computer? BTW, I suggest you to go through the [tour] page.

Answer (score 1):

A non-admin user (without sudo access) is not supposed to install packages or perform updates (that is the whole point of having non-admin users in the first place, so that many people can use a computer, but they won't be able to break the installation even if they unknowingly try to do something wrong).

You can occasionally log in from your (admin) account to perform the updates.
Alternatively, you can [set up](https://askubuntu.com/a/204/124466) unattended upgrades in the admin account, so that Ubuntu would be automatically upgraded when you use the computer.