# Automatic updates paused due to metered connection

Tags: software-center, update-manager

My laptop runs Ubuntu 20.04. I turned on my mobile hotspot and connect to it with my laptop's Wi-Fi to use the internet. Whenever I go to Ubuntu Software Center, this bar is always there:

[image]

If I click the *Find Out More* option, this pop up comes up:

[image]

I checked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9/how-do-i-enable-automatic-updates) and tried some of the proposed answers but nothing is working. My current Software & Updates *Updates* option looks like this:

[image]

What is this? Is it a problem? How to get rid of this?

**Edit 1:** My Wi-Fi is not showing metered, I just checked:

[image]

Comment: It is a very clear message you have metering turned on. It does not turn itself on so you have made this setting.

Comment: "metering" = Charged by your phone carrier for each GB of data you download. The purpose of the setting is to prevent large phone bills caused by downloads you didn't know that your system is doing in the background. Either turn off metering in Network Manager or use an unmetered connection.

Comment: I have not checked the metered option from wifi settings.Please check the new photos

Comment: Please look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

### BUG

Actually, there was a [bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/issues/996) at the time you asked this question that caused gnome-software to believe your connection was metered. Later versions of the software addressed the issue. As a result, you can simply run `sudo apt upgrade` to resolve the issue. You may still be experiencing this problem if you aren't using the deb version. You can install the deb version using:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

You can start it with the command `gnome-software`. You can also use the app drawer to start it.

#### Original answer

This problem is because your current network is metered and Ubuntu does not do automatic updates on metered connections. It shows that panel because automatic updates are paused. Do the following to set the connection to `metered-no`.

Note the following changes will take more internet than usual because of background tasks etc.

##### Command-line Interface

1. Get the device's current connection

   ```
   nmcli -t -f GENERAL.CONNECTION --mode tabular device show $DEVICE | head -n1
   ```

   `-t` is required as there is a space appended at the end
2. Show current metered status

   ```
   nmcli -f connection.metered connection show $CONNECTION
   ```

   Where `$CONNECTION` is the string returned by the previous command.
3. Change metered status

   The valid statuses are `yes`, `no`, and `unknown`. `unknown` is the default, which will do the guessing based on things like the DHCP option 
   eg:- `ANDROID_METERED`
4. Now disable the metered connection:

   ```
   nmcli connection modify $CONNECTION connection.metered no
   ```

   Change `$CONNECTION` by the output of the first command.

##### Graphical User Interface

1. Go to settings (by searching settings in the application launcher and then opening the settings app)
2. There navigate to the Wi-Fi settings:

> [image]

3. There go to the current connection settings
4. You will see a screen like this:

> [image]

5. As you can see my connection isn't metered, but your checkbox may be ticked, so, just untick it and click on `Apply`.

---

If the above didn't work, you can try running this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

You'll get a prompt like:

> [image]

Select `yes` and it'll work.

If you get any other prompt then choose the default options or the options you prefer.

---

If the above also didn't work then there must be some other issue. Try reinstalling the software app or install the `gnome-softaware` app

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

---

If nothing worked, then try changing your update settings to:

> [image]

Comment: I run all the commands you have written output is as follows :
Android
Error: invalid field 'connection.metered'; allowed fields: NAME,UUID,TYPE,TIMES>
lines 1-1/1 (END)
Error: unknown connection 'connection.metered'.



I also added one more photos please see it you might be interested in

Comment: +1  I have the same experience as yoMama33. Op sys doesn't see any metered connection. I wonder if it might be restricted within the mobile network that I use for internet ?

Comment: @Trunk Please look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late, But try this one

Open >> Terminal
Type >> nm-connection-editor

Select & Double Click on Your network

[Network Manager Connection Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBl4C.png)

Then Select >> General >> Metered Connection

Then Choose >> No

[General Tab && Metered Connection Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M03Et.png)

It Worked for Me.

[Store With Problem Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIE3l.png)

Comment: This might solve the question today. But what about later when the links do not work?

Comment: Wait for Ubuntu 22.04, maybe new version will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is this problem in ubuntu 22.04. I try one way and was solution.

1. Open Advanced Network Cofiguration
2. Double click your network name
3. General (first in the menu)
   4.Metered connection  -- No