# One of three systems doesn't upgrade to the latest kernel

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

Three systems, two show ls /boot config-6.2.0-33-generic config-6.2.0-34-generic, The third shows config-6.2.0-32-generic config-6.2.0-33-generic.  `uname -sr` is still Linux 6.2.0-33-generic.

I have rebooted third computer and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` repeated times, but no new kernel is installed. All computers are running Ubuntu 22.04 at

```
Linux ace 6.2.0-33-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep 7   
10:33:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The latest kernel version 6.2.0-34 is installed on two of the three computers. The repository sources lists are the same.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `full-upgrade` on the third computer to upgrade kernel:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

You should probably look into configuring [`unattended-upgrades`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9/how-do-i-enable-automatic-updates) to perform kernel updates.

Comment: Unless they've installed the HWE track of kernels, they won't get the updated HWE kernels.  Metapackages do weird things when they're not installed :P

Comment: I just don't understand how they could have `config-6.2.0-33-generic` (question says so) without the HWE kernel enabled. But anyhow, it got fixed for the OP.

Comment: I can think of several ways, primary way being manual installation of the corresponding linux-image/linux-headers packages WITHOUT the metapackage (because the metapackage just points at the latest corresponding kernel packages), and that's why it doesn't update.  Metapackage does updating, individual kernel packages don't.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Artur Meinild, unfortunately `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` didn't fix it.

However, I did find this command:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04
```

That caused the installation of several new `linux-headers` including Linux `6.2.0-34-generic`.  So now the system is up to date.